# I'm getting the following exception when following the JavaBrains tutorial on Spring Aspect Programming:

Tags: java, exception, spring-aop

I'm following the spring aspect programming tutorials at Javabrains. I'm in this tutorial specifically: http://javabrains.koushik.org/2011/08/spring-tutorial-27-writing-our-first.html I have the required libraries imported into the project and I get no warnings from the IDE, but when I run the code I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/tools/PointcutDesignatorHandler
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:452)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at org.koushik.javabrains.AopMain.main(AopMain.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/tools/PointcutDesignatorHandler
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getPointcut(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:145)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvisor(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:130)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory$1.doWith(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:74)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:473)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:451)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvisors(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.buildAspectJAdvisors(BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.java:109)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:86)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:107)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:278)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:880)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:852)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:446)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutDesignatorHandler
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 28 more
Process finished with exit code 1
```

My class files and spring.xml:

Main class:

```
package org.koushik.javabrains;

import org.koushik.javabrains.service.ShapeService;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class AopMain {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        ShapeService shapeService = ctx.getBean("shapeService",ShapeService.class);
        System.out.println(shapeService.getCircle().getName());
    }
}
```

ShapeService Class:

```
package org.koushik.javabrains.service;

import org.koushik.javabrains.model.Circle;
import org.koushik.javabrains.model.Triangle;


public class ShapeService {

    private Circle circle;
    private Triangle triangle;

    public Circle getCircle() {
        return circle;
    }

    public void setCircle(Circle circle) {
        this.circle = circle;
    }

    public Triangle getTriangle() {
        return triangle;
    }

    public void setTriangle(Triangle triangle) {
        this.triangle = triangle;
    }
}
```

The Circle class:

```
package org.koushik.javabrains.model;

public class Circle {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Triangle class:

```
package org.koushik.javabrains.model;

public class Triangle {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

LoggingAspect class:

```
package org.koushik.javabrains.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before("execution(public String getName())")
    public void loggingAdvice(){
        System.out.println("Advice run. Get Method called");
    }
}
```

spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean name="triangle" class="org.koushik.javabrains.model.Triangle">
        <property name="name" value="triangle"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="circle" class="org.koushik.javabrains.model.Circle">
        <property name="name" value="circle"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="shapeService" class="org.koushik.javabrains.service.ShapeService"   autowire="byName"/>

    <bean name="loggingAspect" class="org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect"/>

</beans>
```

I have read through the comments on the tutorial page, and I have tried with different jars, but non of them seem to work. I always end up with the same exception.

Comment: Do you have the `aspectjweaver` dependency in your POM file?

Comment: I'm not using maven, but yes I was missing aspectjweaver from the classpath.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/tools/PointcutDesignatorHandler

You must add [`aspectjweaver.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.7.1/aspectjweaver-1.7.1.jar) to your CLASSPATH. How to do it precisely depends on your IDE.

Comment: Thanks, yes I completly forgot to add the aspecjweaver.jar to the classpaht. Now its running :)

Answer (score 16):

If using maven add this or any version you need:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```